# What is the point of appending "g "elements to svg when only one attribute is being chained in the grouping?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, visualization

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

How does this differ from

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

My understanding is that "g" is supposed be a grouping of different svg elements. But what's the point of appending g when there's only one proceeding attribute ("transform,"translate")

Comment: Adding "g" elements to an SVG, even if you're only using one attribute, helps with keeping things organized, makes styling and scripting easier, and makes it clearer what each part of the SVG is for. It also makes it simpler to change things later on if you need to. So, basically, using "g" elements helps make SVG files easier to read, maintain, and update. @user20402884

Answer (score 3):

The attributes  don't do the same thing. Setting the `transform` attribute will move the whole `<svg>` element in the HTML page, probably messing with other contents there, while setting it on the `<g>` will only affect the content of that `<g>` which will stay inside the `<svg>` element.

```js
var svg1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(30, 30)")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 30)
  .attr("fill", "blue");
  
var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("transform", "translate(30, 30)")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 30)
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

```css
svg { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```